# Magento, how to edit magento for access magento admin area without authentication

Tags: php, magento

I want to speed test Magento admin area with some 3rd party tool. However I can't do it as Magento admin area requires authentication. Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Magento ships with source and you are allowed to modify it.

Fork the source repo, branch out your testing code-base, hack it and create a patch that you can apply for testing.

After testing inverse-apply the patch.

If the non-test code-base changes, rebase your testing branch on top of it.

Please take note that the tests might be limited, because you do not speed-test the original admin area but a modified one. E.g. the speed tests do not cover those parts that you removed. This might be obvious, however, when you're testing and seeing results this often is somehow forgotten. So leaving a note here.